# Quando usar ENQUANTO, PARA ou REPITA no VisualG (Portugol, Pseudo-código)?

Tags: loop, visualg, portugol

Acabei de realizar o mesmo exercício das 3 maneiras e com uma variação condicional SE (para exibir de forma mais comum) essa soma de 0 a 100..

e me veio a cabeça: em que tipos de caso pode ser mais interessante usar uma ou outra se é possível obter o mesmo resultado com as 3 alternativas?

```
Inicio
escreval (" ")
escreval ("Método ENQUANTO:")
   numero <- 0
   soma <- 0
   //escreva (numero, )
   enquanto numero < 100 faca
   numero <- numero + 1
   soma <- soma + numero

   escreva (numero)
   fimenquanto
   escreval (" ")
   escreval (" ")
   escreval ("A Soma de 1 a 100 é: ", soma)
   
   escreval (" ")
//----------------------------------------
escreval ("Método PARA:")
   numero <- 1
   soma <- 0
   
   para numero de 1 ate 100 faça
   soma <- soma + numero   //a ordem de atribuiçao faz diferença
   escreva (numero)
   numero <- numero+1

   fimpara
escreval (" ")
escreval (" ")
escreval ("A Soma de 1 a 100 é: ", soma)
//----------------------------------------
escreval (" ")
escreval ("Método REPITA:")
   numero <- 0
   soma <-0
   repita
   numero <- numero + 1
   soma <- soma+numero
   escreva (numero, " ")
   ate numero = 100
   
   escreval (" ")
   escreval (" ")
   escreval ("A Soma de 1 a 100 é: ", soma)
   //fimrepita   (comando desnecessário
   
escreval (" ")
escreval ("Método ENQUANTO(2):")  //um pouco mais apresentável
   numero <- 0
   soma <- 0
   //escreva (numero, "  +")
      enquanto numero < 100 faca
      
      numero <- numero + 1
      soma <- soma + numero
      
         se numero = 100 então

         escreval (numero, " = ", soma)
         senao
         escreva (numero, " +")
         fimse
      fimenquanto
   escreval (" ")
   escreval (" ")
   escreval ("a soma foi: ", soma)

   escreval (" ")
//---------------------------------------

escreval ("Método PARA(2):") //
   numero <- 1
   soma <- 0

   para numero de 1 ate 100 faça

   soma <- soma + numero   //adicionando o SE a ordem de atrubuição inverteu

         se numero = 100 então

         escreval (numero," =", soma)

         senao
         
         escreva (numero, " +") //foi preciso representar primeiro
         numero <- numero+1    //para depois incrementar até o se=TRUE
         fimse
   fimpara


   
//---------------------------------------
escreval (" ")
escreval ("Método REPITA(2):")
   numero <- 0
   soma <-0
   repita
   numero <- numero+1
   soma <- soma+numero
         se numero = 100 então
         escreval (numero," =", soma)
         senao

         escreva (numero, " +")

         fimse
   
   
   ate numero = 100

   escreval (" ")
   //escreval ("a soma foi: ", soma)
   //fimrepita   (comando desnecessário


//---------------------------------------

Fimalgoritmo
```

Comment: Olá Marcos, `enquanto` e `repita` são "iguais" é um questão da tua escolha pessoal, o `para` usamos "normalmente" para um contador que se sabe antecipadamente o que ser contar, por exemplo "de 1 a 10" ou "de 100 a 900 de 100 em 100", etc.

Comment: sugiro também ler a documentação do visual G para saber mais: [manual visualG](http://www.inf.ufsc.br/~bosco.sobral/ensino/ine5201/Visualg2_manual.pdf)

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Gostaria de saber casos práticos que podem ser preferíveis um ou outro, pois através dos 3 é possível chegar ao mesmo resultado sem tanta diferenciação de quantas linhas de código é necessário. Gostaria de saber se não é apenas uma questão arbitrária de cada programador.